# Visual Studio Button Event

Tags: vb.net

I would like to code a button that after 3 clicks, links the user to my site. The first 2 should generate a code in the textbox and the last one should then link them. This is what i have so far

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(3)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Thank you"
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Start()
    ElseIf RadioButton2.checked = True Then
        Timer1.Start()
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Please Select Option"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i find it rude people are down voting this post for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the use of ProgressBar and Timer. But if you wan to know how many times user has click on a button, a counter variable should do.

```
Private _clickCounter As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    _clickCounter += 1

    If _clickCounter = 3 Then
        MsgBox("3 times")
        _clickCounter = 0
        'link to your site
    Else
        'generate code in textbox
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, i'm assuming that i could just replace the part about message box display with a command to open a webpage?

Comment: yes, you can just replace whatever action you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Use an integer that increases each time the button is clicked and a `Select Case` statement to detect that;

```
Dim NumberOfClicks As Integer = 0

Dim webAddress As String = "http://www.YourWebsite.com/"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 number = number + 1
 Select Case number
      Case 1
          ''''' Code for your textbox
      Case 2
          ''''' Code for your textbox
      Case 3
           Process.Start(webAddress)
End Sub
```

This should do. Please mark my answer as solved if it helps.